# How to handle a state update after a redux thunk action dispatch in a function within a class component?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to delete a team when a user clicks on a button. The functionality works good, but now i am in a phase where i want to send the right notification message to the user.

I manage my alerts in redux so, for example if the delete action fails or succeed my state will be updated with the actual state of the alert.

My problem is that when i fire the click event, the state is not changed and the user gets the old alert notification. When the team is deleted in the end the state does change as expected.

```
onDelete = () => {
  // Here i am dispatching a action to delete the team, which is working fine and updates the state
  this.props.deleteTeam(this.state.team);

  // So here i want to check if the action was succesfull, but it is the old value of the state
  if (this.props.alert.type === 'success') {
       this.hideModalHandler();

       // Same here i am sending the old alert message to the user
       alertService.success(this.props.alert.message, false, false);
  }
};
```

So my question is: is there way to make the function wait untill the state is updated, so that i can use the actual state, and not the old. I tried using async await, but unfortunately that is not working.

Your help is appreciated, thnx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably better off having your alert handler as an action in itself. That way it can query getState() to get the most up-to-date data. Makes it more reusable too if you need to check the alert status elsewhere.